# Create a request waiting-list on NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, request, node-fetch

I'd like to build a NodeJS server that responds to requests just one at the time.

Basically: by doing `fetch('<domain>/request/<id>` I want that untill the client received the data the other requests are queued. Is it possible?

Comment: It surely is possible. One request per IP/session or one request in total ?

Comment: @BrahmaDev one in total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An npm module like `express-queue` could work.

```
var express = require('express');
var queue = require('express-queue');
var app = express();
app.use(queue({
    activeLimit: 1
}));

app.use("*", function(req, res, next) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        res.send("OK");
    }, 2000);
});
app.listen(3000);
```